# unable to bind data with ion-item in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app, angular2-services

Working on `ionic-2` with `angular 2`, I am getting an array of objects in which I get details of an individual.

I have declared a var `dataObj:any` to assign the values I get from my object. I have successfully even assigned the values to the object, But I am still unable to show or bind those value in HTML / Template

**Class:**

```
export class DetailsPage {
  id: any;
  public dataObj: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public absService: AbsconderService, public posService: PosService) {   
     this.id = navParams.get('id'); 
     this.getData(this.id)
  }

   getData(id) {
    this.absService.getAbsconderById(id)
      .then(data => {
        this.dataObj = {
          name : data.data[0].name,
          nic : data.data[0].nic,
          fname: data.data[0].fname,
          caste: data.data[0].caste,
          residence: data.data[0].residence,
          crime_no: data.data[0].crime_no,
          us: data.data[0].us,
          ps: data.data[0].ps
        }
           console.log(this.dataObj);  
      })
  };


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Details');
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>

      <ion-col col-12>
        <img class="background-image-sp" src="assets/images/avtar.png" />
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{dataObj.name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>NIC No.</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{dataObj.nic}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: what are you seeing??? just nothing... is there an error in you console?

Comment: does this line show anything `console.log(this.dataObj); `??

Comment: yah it show data as expected

Comment: is the rest of the page showing correctly.... (like the image?)

Comment: could it be because you are making an Async call in the constructor so the when the page renders is still to early for the response to comeback??

Comment: Well, surprised, due Async call and I was in debug mode in Inspect Element. Just disabled and worked fine. no changes were made.

Comment: so you did not have to use `ChangeDetectorRef `?

Comment: yes, ofcourse. Now it is working well

Comment: cool happy coding

Comment: @PatoSalazar I don't know how it was working then. But now its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529260/error-error-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-un)

Answer (score 3):

could it be because you are making an Async call in the constructor so the when the page renders is still to early for the response to comeback??. Also I have run into this in Ionic 3... you would expect that data binds will update themselves when their value changes... but sometimes you need to call that change manually using

`import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`

assign this object to a property in the constructor:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public absService: AbsconderService, public posService: PosService, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {   
     this.id = navParams.get('id'); 
     this.getData(this.id)
}
```

And call it in your then block at the end

```
       getData(id) {
    this.absService.getAbsconderById(id)
      .then(data => {
        this.dataObj = {
          name : data.data[0].name,
          nic : data.data[0].nic,
          fname: data.data[0].fname,
          caste: data.data[0].caste,
          residence: data.data[0].residence,
          crime_no: data.data[0].crime_no,
          us: data.data[0].us,
          ps: data.data[0].ps
        }
           console.log(this.dataObj);
           changeDetector.detectChanges()
      })  
};
```

You can try this. Let me know

Comment: can we use this `changeDetector.detectChanges()` to make async call to finish all his proceedings first ?

Comment: Hi @PatoSalazar, your answer is nice. Could you please tell more when to use or not to use `ChangeDetectorRef`? Or can you refer some documents?

Comment: @Duannx this link helped me a lot... good luck `https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html`

Comment: @PatoSalazar Thank you so much!