# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am getting an error in my ionic 2 application with angular 2, first this

> runtime error Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

secondly this

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'name' of undefined

and finally this

> ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 14, nodeDef:
>   Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}

some times change in sequence but all error are coming.

**code**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html',
})
export class DetailsPage {
  id: any;
  public dataObj: any;
  public Records: any

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public absService: AbsconderService, public posService: PosService) {   
     this.id = navParams.get('id'); 
     console.log('constructor');
     this.getData(this.id)

  }

   getData(id) {
     console.log('service called');
    this.absService.getAbsconderById(id)
      .then(data => {
        this.Records = data;
        this.dataObj  = {
          name : this.Records.data[0].name,
          nic : this.Records.data[0].nic,
          fname: this.Records.data[0].fname,
          caste: this.Records.data[0].caste,
          residence: this.Records.data[0].residence,
          crime_no: this.Records.data[0].crime_no,
          us: this.Records.data[0].us,
          ps: this.Records.data[0].ps
        }
        console.log(this.dataObj);


      })

  };


  ionViewDidLoad() {

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Details');
  }

}
```

**Template**

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{dataObj.name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>NIC No.</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{dataObj}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataObj` gets filled in from `AJAX`, so initial Change detection cycle is trying to evaluate `dataObj.name` expression where `dataObject` doesn't have value.

You should use `safe navigation operator` on HTML in such cases.

```
<ion-label>{{dataObj?.name}}</ion-label>
```

---

Better way to handle it would be have using `*ngIf else`, and show loading content till data comes through `AJAX`.

```
<ion-content padding *ngIf="dataObj else dataLoading">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{dataObj.name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>NIC No.</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{dataObj}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
<ng-template #dataLoading>
   <ion-content padding>
     <ion-item>
       <ion-label stacked>NIC No.</ion-label>
       <ion-label>{{dataObj}}</ion-label>
     </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: to handle this by putting ?.

Comment: putting ? solved my issue. can we handle this from .js file?